# How do I change an incorrect contribution status to Completed?

Tags: civicontribute, iats, failure

An EFT/ACH contribution was made last week via a Civi Contribution page with no price sets.  Normally EFT transactions go through just fine, but this one hit a snag and was marked Pending and then Failed by our vendor, iATS.  The iATS website gave a reject code I didn't recognize (113), so I inquired with their customer service.  Turns out it was an temporary communication issue with their system and the bank, and so the Failed status wasn't actually true.  It was a successful transaction.  iATS corrected the status in their system yesterday.

Our issue now is that Civi still says Failed.  I tried to edit the transaction via the Civi UI, but my only options now for the Contribution Status are Failed, Partially Paid, or Pending Refund.

1. Is there a workaround in the UI to edit this transaction and make it Completed?
2. Or do I need to edit the transaction in the `civicrm_contribution` table with the `contribution_status_id` field?  (It is currently `4`; I would change it to `1`.)
3. Are there any potential issues with changing the contribution status directly in the database?

*Drupal 7, Civi 4.6, iATS extension 1.5.3*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the CiviCRM GUI indeed does not let you change Failed to Completed - and I'm pretty sure that's because it would mean edits to the all financial table entries associated with that Contribution. So yes you can edit the status_id in the contribution table - just keep in mind that you will want to also check all financial tables and adjust/add entries - that is if you use CiviAccounting features. Having said that on 4.6 - recurring installments generated with completeTransaction API don't end up in all Financial tables - so you probably already know to keep an eye out for that. So yes 4 -> 1.

Comment: Thank you Karen for your reminder about adjusting and adding entries. I just finished, and it took me a little bit to track down the various entries I needed.  I think I'll add another SE question just going through that process.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge:

As far as the contribution hasn't exported to any sage or anything you are ok - you can directly change the contribution status against the DB which will be an easy fix.

But if the transaction has been exported already then we shouldn't be change the status instead we should be creating an new transaction for the contact also mention the reason against the source which will help.

I guess this helps!!!